# Need to change "localhost:3000" written in web-push notifications

Tags: node.js, npm, push-notification, notifications, web-push

I recently setup push notifications using web-push in a Node application... Here's a sample:
[image]

I want the origin of notification to show the domain name as **websiteName.com** and **not localhost:3000**. How should I do it? Here's the notification body:

```
notification: {
            title: "Sample Message",
            body: "Did someone tell you you're awesome? ;-)",
            icon: global.domain + '/dp/' + (currentUser['dp'] || null),
            vibrate: [100, 50, 100],
            data: {
                dateOfArrival: Date.now(),
                primaryKey: 1,
                url: "google.com"
            },
            actions: [{
                action: "explore",
                title: "Checkout",
                icon: global.domain + '/default/jolly-roger.png',
            }]
        }
```

Using Node 16, running on Ubuntu server 18. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My bad. It was a problem of cache. Cleaning the server and browser cached solved the problem. Thanks (._.!)